# Not receiving eMail

Tags: php, html, email

I'm confused with what the problem is, I'm not receiving any e-mail whilst using the mail php function.

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="named23" size="12">
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" nowrap valign="top">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CHK_NOCACHE" value="on">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <div>
        <input type="submit" name="ch_but_logon" value="Entrer">
</form>
```

MAILER.PHP

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['ch_but_logon'])) {
    $txt = $_POST['named23'];   
    mail("psadsaxu@yahoo.sds","test",$txt);
}

?>
```

Comment: The error is that i am NOT receiving any emails.

Comment: Come on, how many times are you going to post this same code?

Comment: @user876345 it's beceuse i wanted to hide my email,but when i do it on my server i put propoer email@yahoo.com

Comment: @Barmar until i will have the solution :/ i am trying this few hours and nothing.

Comment: @user876345 Yes checked spam folder,and inbox folder , it's just not coming . I Don't understand.

Comment: Instead of yahoo id, just use gmail email address to verify. Are you sending from local or server ?

Comment: @user876345  I Tried GMAIL/YAHOO , the SMTP/SERVER is working beceuse i downlaoded a form submiter,and it sended the email to me . But homever this doesn't work,no clue why :/

Comment: add headers too. check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

***Syntax***

```
mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters)
```

***PHP Simple E-Mail***

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

***PHP Mail Form***

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))
//if "email" is filled out, send email
  {
  //send email
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
  mail("someone@example.com", $subject,
  $message, "From:" . $email);
  echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
  }
else
//if "email" is not filled out, display the form
  {
  echo "<form method='post' action='mailform.php'>
  Email: <input name='email' type='text'><br>
  Subject: <input name='subject' type='text'><br>
  Message:<br>
  <textarea name='message' rows='15' cols='40'>
  </textarea><br>
  <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```